# Directory.GetFiles not returning the correct number of files

Tags: c#

I have a function fire every 2 minutes from a Threading.Timer. The function goes through a directory (hardcoded in) and deletes all .ev1 files in it. This directory is on a server and has a file moved to it every ~2 minutes.

It worked for about a day or so, the directory was empty, or had 1 file in it. Now I went to check it and there's 746 files in it. I put a breakpoint after this line:

```
String[] Files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(MachineDir, WatcherFileType, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Where MachineDir is the directory I'm looking at (I double checked that the directory string is correct). WatcherFileType is .ev1.

Is there some bug with Directory.GetFiles? or possibly something with running this app for extended periods of time.

Comment: I highly doubt there's a bug in the framework class.

Comment: OK, so you put a breakpoint after that line and what happened? Did the breakpoint hit? If so, how many files were in the array?

Comment: Is it possible that an exception is thrown while deleting the file.

Comment: I was just listing out possibilites. It's most likely my fault, but if you read my response to the answer below, there have been times where it was microsoft's error.

Comment: Yes the breakpoint hit, and Files.length showed 0.

Comment: There was no exception. I have them printed out to the console if they occur. I set a breakpoint on the catch just incase.

Comment: its not a bug..it happens with extentions with 3 characters such as txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting WatcherFileType to "*.ev1"

Also you might want to look into the FileSystemWatcher object which doesn't use polling:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: This was the inital way I went about it, unfortunately there is a bug with Microsoft's nfs mounts. The ev1 files are transferred via nfs mount and Microsoft doesn't notify of file changes through nfs mounts. They released this hotfix, but I couldn't ever get it working. http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;894537 this was the only alternative really.

Comment: changing the WatcherFileType from ".ev1" to "*.ev1" fixed it.

Comment: @tareqx3 be aware that it would also match `.ev133`,`.ev13dsds`

Comment: I know. The only files added to the folder are evt and ev1 files. They also require a naming scheme. If the naming scheme doesn't fit, the files are left alone.

Comment: @anirudha that is not correct.  It will not match either of those examples.

Comment: @Dharun read the remark note [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx)

Comment: @Anirudha I am aware, but you are misunderstanding the caveat on MSDN

Comment: @Dharun ohh..common..r u a kid.. `.txt` is exactly similar to `.ev1`

Answer (score -1):

Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) extract from **MSDN**

When the extension is exactly three characters,`GetFiles` would return all the extensions that **match** and that **starts** with that 3 letter extension.

So,
`*.txt` would match `hello.txt`,`hello.txter`,`hello.txtworld`

Insted use `?.txt` which would match `hello.txt` exactly.

This problem is only with 3 letter extention

So you should use

```
?.ev1
```

Comment: This is not correct the three letter extension caveat does not imply this